# Pandas join rows if at least one cell is NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe build from text extracted from a PDF file.
It looks like this:

```
index      date         description1        description2        value1        value2
   0       18-01-2019    some                  more                1             2
   1       NaN           text                  text                NaN           NaN
   2       NaN           here                   NaN                NaN           NaN
   3       19-01-2019    some                  some                3             4
   4       NaN           text                  more                NaN           NaN
   5       NaN           here                  text                NaN           NaN
   6       NaN            NaN                  here                NaN           NaN
   .
   .
   .
```

There is always at least 1 row with no NaN, and that row will always contain the Date and the Values. Only the Descriptions are on multiple rows.

Is there a way to join the rows, based on, say, date, with the rows bellow until the value in not NaN, and join the description?

Expected output:

```
index      date         description1        description2           value1        value2
   0       18-01-2019    some text here      more text              1             2
   1       19-01-2019    some text here      some more text here    3             4
   .
   .
   .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is create column for grouping by forward filling `date` (or some any column used for distinguish groups) and then if numeric get first value else use `join` with remove missing values:

```
f = lambda x: x.iloc[0] if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ' '.join(x.dropna())
```

Or specify each columns in dictionary:

```
f1 = lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())

f = {'date':'first', 'description1':f1, 'description1':f1, 'value1':'first', 'value2':'first'}
```

What should be created dynamically create both dicts and merge together:

```
f1 = lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())

c =['description1','description2']
d1 = dict.fromkeys(c, f1)
d2 = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(c), 'first')
f = {**d1, **d2}
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(df['date'].ffill()).agg(f).reset_index(drop=True)
#alternative
#df = df.groupby(df['date'].ffill(), as_index=False).agg(f)

print (df)
         date    description1         description2  value1  value2
0  18-01-2019  some text here            more text     1.0     2.0
1  19-01-2019  some text here  some more text here     3.0     4.0
```

Comment: as_index=False can also be used as an alternative for reset_index right?

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Dtypes for columns are: date: datetime64; description1 and description2: str; value1 and value2: float64

Comment: @PetruTanas - What solution?

Comment: @jezrael I have tried the first one, and the dynamic one.

Comment: @PetruTanas - What is your pandas version? Because for me working nice

Comment: @jezrael pandas==0.25.2, numpy==1.17.3 on py 3.8. Could it be a python 3.8 issue? I had a lot of problems with most modules, as there is no support yet

Comment: @PetruTanas - Tested in pandas 3.7 problem is with sample data or with real data?

Comment: @jezrael In real data. Figured it out. Description sometimes contained a number which pandas classified as int, instead of text, and then fails to perform the join, forcing type str for description fixed it. At least that is what I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use fillna with ffill, then groupby this timestamp, then do stuff with the description inside agg:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].fillna(method='ffill')

df_new = df.groupby('date').agg({'description1': lambda x: ' '.join(x.values)})
```

Update: probably, for your output format, you would need to manipulate indices a little bit, like this:

```
df_new = df.groupby('date', as_index=False).agg({'description1': lambda x: ' '.join(x.values)}).reset_index(drop=True)
```